# Autostart postgres on Manjaro

Tags: postgresql, systemd, manjaro

I installed postres using pacman on Manjaro. 
When I do:

```
su postgres
postgres -D ~/data >~/logs/log
```

I get

```
FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
```

And so, every time I boot up I have to

```
sudo su
mkdir /run/posgresql
chown postgres:postgres /run/posgresql
```

I tried creating /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service as described in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/server-start.html, but the service doesn't run on startup?
Why isn't the folder persisting after reboot?  Is there a better way of starting up postgres? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using the "service" approach is the proper way. It will ensure the creation of the lockfile for you. If you want it to autostart, you need to run the `enable` command on your service.

```
systemctl enable postgresql
```